# nginx server_name while setting up Django project

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I've entered my IP address in server_name and it's perfectly working. And I forwarded my domain to the respected IP address but when I open my domain address it's showing 'Welcome to Nginx', not my web application.

Do I've to provide domain in nginx sites available??

Comment: 'Welcome to Nginx' means that there is another `server` block which is the `default_server` and matching any request that does not explicitly match your `server_name` directive. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all files and remove the other `server` block if it is causing you problems.

Comment: @RichardSmith, yeah because at the time of setting up sites-available I didn't provide the domain name, I only provide IP there. should I replace the IP with the domain?

Comment: The 'Welcome to Nginx' is a demo to demonstrate that you have installed Nginx correctly. If it was me, I'd get rid of it. If you decide to keep it, you need to use **all of the names** your website will respond to. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to edit Nginx site-available, it worked for as I added my domain name with and without "www." to ALLOWED_HOST in settings.py and in Nginx's site-available I just replaced my IP my domain name with and without "www." and that's it, now just restart gunicorn and Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

On installing nginx by default it will take port **80**, if you see default config file in the path **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**, you can see the default port will listen to 80, either you change the default port 80 to some other port, or change your current project port to some other port and finally restart the nginx to see the changes. Hope this might help you!

Comment: so can't I use my application on port 80?

Comment: U can use, that is what i mentioned, change the default port 80 to some other port in the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default